# I need to show $x_n \to \infty$ implies $f(x_n) \to L$?

Tags: real-analysis

Assuming $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$, $(a , \infty) \subseteq A$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f = L$, and $(x_n) \in A \cap (0, \infty)$ is such that $x_n \to \infty$, then show $f(x_n) \to L$.

Attempt:

I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f = L$ means that given any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $k_1 = k(\epsilon) > a$ such that $|f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ when $x > k_1$.

And also, from $x_n \to \infty$, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, we can find some $k_2 = k(\alpha)$ such that $x_n > \alpha$ when $n \ge k_2$.

I am stuck with what to do next. I need to show $|f(x_n) - L| < \epsilon$ when $n \ge N$. I don't know how to find such an $N$ so that I can use the above conditions. I've considered $N = \max\{k_1, k_2\}$, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that for $x > k_1$, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ and you'd like to get $|f(x_n) - L|< \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ where you are free to choose $N$. That means you'd like to guarantee that for all $n \geq N$, $x_n > k_1$. But since $x_n \to \infty$ you can choose $k_2$ such that $n \geq k_2$ implies $x_n > k_1$. So this value of $N = k_2$ does the trick. (take $\alpha = k_1$ and $k_2 = k(k_1)$ using your notation)